# Change player url when click on item on list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to build some kind of channel site.
When user clicks on a href name of channel then url of streaming url changes without reloading the page.

My code is

```
    <div class="player-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="player-container">
                <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id="player" data="GrindPlayer.swf" width="640" height="480" style="visibility: visible;"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"><param name="wmode" value="opaque"><param name="flashvars" value="autoPlay=true&amp;src=rtmp%3A//XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX%3A1935/livelowedge/nickelodeon.stream%23.m3u8&amp;streamType=live&amp;scaleMode=letterbox&amp;plugin_hls=flashlsOSMF.swf&amp;hls_debug=false&amp;hls_debug2=false&amp;hls_minbufferlength=-1&amp;hls_lowbufferlength=2&amp;hls_maxbufferlength=60&amp;hls_startfromlowestlevel=false&amp;hls_seekfromlowestlevel=false&amp;hls_live_flushurlcache=false&amp;hls_seekmode=ACCURATE&amp;hls_capleveltostage=false&amp;hls_maxlevelcappingmode=downscale"></object>
                <div id="player-tip" style="display: none;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

As you can see, i have nickelodeon.stream loaded.
I wish when user click on a href TV1 to play rtmp://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:1935/livelowedge/TV1.stream
and so on.
I hope i could explain it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: So what is the issue? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not post any code, but i'm still gonna try to help you.
You could do this by doing something like prefix and suffix (I hope that the XXX is meant to be replaced) like:

```
function stream(stream) {
  var url = "rtmp://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:1935/livelowedge/" + stream;
  return url; //If you want to process it 
  //or
  window.location = url; //If you want to redirect to that stream
}
```

Or you could do this by splitting the string into an array, replacing the wanted part and then joining it all back together.

**EDIT:**

I came up with these two easy solutions, i wouldn't really encourage you to use the second one if you don't really need to process the contents of the `a` tag:
 - [First](https://jsfiddle.net/n32h0zjc/1/)
 - [Second](https://jsfiddle.net/aqos156/r0qqu202/2/) 
You souldn't really need anything else than this. These things are html, javascript basics which you should know.

Comment: no XXX is IP address hidden. Replaced need to be TV1.stream
With TV2.stream, TV3.stream etc and so on.
You got me?
When someone click a href TV 1 player loads that stream.
And yes i posted code , here is it again

Comment: So you just need to replace the "TV1.stream", and do you need to replace the "livelowedge" ??

Comment: I have changed the code, if i still don't get it, could you explain it a bit more? The best thing which you could do is add the code you already have.

Comment: <a href="#">TV1</a>

Comment: <a href="#">TV1</a>

Comment: <a href="#">TV1</a>
<a href="#">TV2</a>
<a href="#">TV3</a>

And I want when user click on these, stream changes

Comment: to tv1stream.stream or nickelodeon.stream
You got me now?

Comment: I've edited my answer, you should be able to do this now, if you want we could go jsfiddle's colab thing. But you should know this.